# Matplotlib only plot to x=250 and redraw

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a txt file where I collect my data from and plot this with python matplotlib.
The text file is structured like this:

```
0 27.087
1 26.132
2 26.021
3 25.897
4 ...
....
// so basically "x temp"
```

I plot (it's a subplot) this with matplotlib with the following piece of code:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(3,2,2, axisbg='grey')
ax.plot(x, temp, 'c', linewidth=2)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='c')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='c')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('w')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('w')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('w')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('w')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('c')
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('c')
ax.set_title('Temperatuur', color = 'c')
```

It is plotting fine until I get more than 250 measurements. It restarts drawing at `x = 0`. And draw over the 'older' plot. Like this:
[image]

But how can I make the x-axis as long as the amount of measurements?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like an overflow problem (255 is the maximum value you can store in one byte). Are you specifying a data type when reading the file?

Comment: How areyou reading in your file?
try `x, Temp = numpy.loadtxt(filename, unpack=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect all the `x` values to be consecutive, you can just leave out the `x` in your plot command:

```
ax.plot(temp, 'c', linewidth=2)
```

That will automatically plot by index.

Comment: `consecutive` *and* equidistant.

Comment: When you're talking about integers [consecutive implies equidistant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/consecutive). Consecutive is a stricter requirement than increasing.